# What is the probability of an occurrence within an interval

Tags: probability, self-study, poisson-distribution

I am having an issue getting my head around this question as well. Gale-force winds occur on the average of 0.7 times every 54 hours.  For an interval of 110 hours whats the probability r = 2?

I believe I should solve it with Poisson Distribution (as it is in this weeks lesson, and question references using two decimal places for lambda).  I would like to know the methodology - not necessarily the answer, but if the answer was supplied it might help me work back and forth through the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Break the problem into steps. First, what's the rate per 110 hours? Second, given the rate, is that enough to compute Poisson probabilities?

Comment: By the way, I think this is a terrible time to use a Poisson model. The fact that there is a hurricane season means the rate isn't constant. Depending on your definition, a single hurricane may generate several several gale force wind events clumped together more than you would expect from a Poisson model. You should know how to use the Poisson model, but I hope the next question is to reject it.

Comment: I guess I am learning, are you suggesting the Poisson model is over applied, or just poorly applied in this overly academic example?

Comment: I'm saying a Poisson distribution is probably a bad model for this particular example.

Comment: I agree with @DouglasZare. This homework problem certainly has a Poisson model in mind, but it's not really the right model here due to the likely clumping.

Comment: I see. What would be a better real world model to apply?  How would this be solved "in the field"?

Answer (score 3):

1. Calculate $\lambda$:

   $$\eqalign{
     0.7/54 &= x/110 \\
     &=  0.7 / 54 \times 110 \\
     &\approx  1.43.
     }$$
2. Solve for $\Pr(r=2)$:

   $$\Pr( r = 2 )  = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^r}{r!} = e^{-1.43}\frac{1.43^2}{2!} = 0.2443.$$

Comment: +1. A check, using `R`: `dpois(2, 0.7 * 110 / 54)` returns $0.2442824$.